# How to compare request->id from id (pk) of one of my database table?

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a `$request->input('coffee_id)` and `$request->input('roastWeight');` to get the id which is from blade.
Then I need to compare the `$request->coffee_id` to coffee_id from the DB table Coffee and get the weight 
Once we get the weight from DB Coffee I need to minus the weight to the `$request->roastWeight` and save to my roast table which named as remainingweight.

```
$coffeeId = $request->input('coffee_id');
$roastId = $request->input('roastWeight'); 

$roast = DB::table('coffee')->join('coffee_roast', 'coffee.coffee_id', '=', 'coffee_roast.coffee_id')->select('coffee_id','weight')->get();
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Your code just looks like the first bit of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: if ($coffeeId == $roast){
    echo ('ok');
}
else echo('err'); i get err only is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I assume `coffee_id` is an integer? Then it'll never be the same as the object inside of `$roast`.

Comment: $user = Auth::user()->id;
$roastid = Roast::value('id');
    $coffeeId = $request->input('coffee_id');
    $roastId = $request->input('roastWeight');
    $roast = DB::table('coffee')
            ->join('coffee_roast', 'coffee.coffee_id', '=', 'coffee_roast.coffee_id')
            ->value('coffee.coffee_id');

 if($roastid == $user){ 
        if ($coffeeId == $roast){
         echo ('ok'); }
            else echo('err');  } i got the output ok so the next step i should get is the weight from coffee DB so that i can minus the $request->input(roastweight). How can i get by any chance?